# more than 2 should blocks in context doesn't work

Tags: ruby, shoulda

```
    context "test"
    should "go to site"
    should "fill 1st page"
    should "fill 2nd page"
```

it worked properly till I add 3rd "should". In selenium server log i see that test begin from 2nd "should" block.
If I delete 2nd and 3rd block then 1st works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it performs alphabetically

```
should "1. go to site"
should "2. fill 1st page"
```